# Canvas problems in Angular (Cannot set property 'lineWidth' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas

I'm trying to make Angular component that contains canvas element that you can use as a drawing tool.

It compiles successfully but as soon as I click on canvas two errors show up:

ERROR TypeError: this.draw is not a function

ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'lineWidth' of undefined

Component code:

```
export class WhiteboardComponent implements OnInit {

  board: HTMLCanvasElement;
  ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D;
  active: boolean = false;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.board = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('board');
    this.ctx = this.board.getContext('2d');

    this.board.addEventListener("mousedown", this.startDrawing);
    this.board.addEventListener("mouseup", this.endDrawing);
    this.board.addEventListener("mousemove", this.draw);

  }


  startDrawing(e: MouseEvent): void {

    this.active = true;
    this.draw(e);

    console.log("start drawing: active:" + this.active);

  }

  endDrawing(): void {

    this.active = false;
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    console.log("end drawing: active:" + this.active);
  }

  draw(e: MouseEvent): void {

    console.log("drawing...");

    if (!this.active) { return; }

    this.ctx.lineWidth = 10;
    //this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    this.ctx.lineCap = "round";
    this.ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind the event listeners to the component scope:

```
this.board.addEventListener("mousedown", this.startDrawing.bind(this));
this.board.addEventListener("mouseup", this.endDrawing.bind(this));
this.board.addEventListener("mousemove", this.draw.bind(this));
```

alternate:

```
    this.board.addEventListener("mousemove", (evt) => {
        console.info(evt);
        this.draw(evt);
    });
```